# Why do two different multimeters show completely different resistance readings?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, multimeter

I just received a brand new Brymen 869s and I'm concerned it may be broken as it's giving a strange reading.

When measuring a 100k 0603 resistor which is soldered into a PCB (forming part of a larger circuit) I get the following readings:

- Direction away from J1: 3.29MΩ
- Direction towards J1: 2.02MΩ

I took some the same readings using a different multimeter, a Proster VC99 and got these readings:

- Direction away from J1: 100kΩ
- Direction towards J1: 8.66kΩ

At J1 there is a 10kHz 2Vpp sine wave.

Why would the Brymen show a value above 100kΩ whereas my cheapo Proster VC99 does not? Surely there's no way that the resistance can be larger than 100k in this circuit.

Here's the signal processing part of the circuit with the 100k resistor marked by the blue arrow. There are 4 similar circuits in the whole PCB since this is a 4 x voltage controlled amplifier circuit. [image]

There's also a power supply. [image]

Comment: Did you disconnect one side of the resistor before taking any measurements? If you did not then any result is unreliable...

Comment: Test them on a stand-alone resistors first.

Comment: We would be speculating on the cause without seeing the surrounding circuitry.  I suspect protection diodes may be at least a part of it.  Also, I suspect your cheapo meter is somewhat more generous with its sense current (this can be verified by using each meter to measure the voltage across a stand-alone resistor while its resistance is being measured with the other).  Are you completely powered down when measuring, caps drained and everything?

Comment: I have voted to close the question because it is unclear what you are asking. Without knowing **exactly** the circuit the resistor is in, it is impossible to provide an answer.

Comment: Brymen seems to have in-circuit errors from reactive elements

Comment: The Brymen is broken, or you're not probing correctly. No matter what else you have connected across a 100k resistor, it will never read more than 100k.

Comment: To answer some questions: the board is completely powered down. Both meters have been tested on a 100k resistor and both read 100k. I'm interested in the reasons why 2 multimeters give different readings in this particular scenario.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, yes this is exactly what I feared. I've updated the question to make it clearer that this is what I'm asking.

Comment: @Dave Tweed Very often charged capacitors may hold enough voltage to cheat an ohmmeter even after minutes from power off. It's not uncommon to measure more than resistor itself  even on a good one

Comment: @carloc: Yes, that's possible, but I don't see any significant capacitors in the schematic. And even when that happens, you usually get vastly different measurements in different directions.

Comment: I believe this question has enough detail now to be reopened.

Comment: The short answer is that in-circuit measurements of resistance is unreliable.  Measuring in different directions will get different answers, and different meter designs are going to come up with different answers.  In-circuit measurements when power is applied, or when capacitors have not discharged, will be even greater.  **In general**, if a board is completely powered down (none applied, no charge on capacitors), a resistor should always read true or lower -- but that "if" is a pretty big "if".  If the meters read correctly out of circuit, they're OK, though.

Comment: Thank you! The comments about charged capacitors triggered me to see if any current would flow if I shorted the 100k resistor (by using the mA range on my Brymen). Sure enough there was current flow for a few seconds. The readings were still off, however, until I realised that my signal generator plugged into J1 was still generating a 2V sine wave. Unplugging this as well and both meters now show the same reading. Turns out the Brymen was trying to tell me something. I feel somewhat stupid, but I also learned quite a few things. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Please guys, _answer_ the question. OP can't do anything with a comment.

Comment: you are turning on ESD structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> resistor which is soldered into a PCB (forming part of a larger
>   circuit)

DMMs measure resistance by applying small current and measuring the resulting voltage. Then assuming that the component is pure passive resistor, the DMM calculates the value in accord with Ohm's Law.

The issue is that when a resistor is a part of a larger circuit, the resulting net contains semiconductor-kind elements and possibly active sources as not fully discharged capacitors. Semiconductor have non-linear dependence on current direction and applied voltage. This would explain one difference. The higher than nominal resistance could be shown if there are active sources that confuse DMM algorithm.

The circuit in question is a 4-channel variable-gain amplifier. It has power supply part that is not shown on schematics:

[image]

This hidden part must have bypass capacitors.

Now, the V2164SZ IC likely has clamping diodes as ESD protection. While the DMM usually applies small probing voltage, 0.2- 0.3V, high impedance measurements require higher voltage. For example, my Fluke 179 applies up to 3.8V in autorange mode. So it is possible that the probing voltage from DMM charges these bypass caps through clamping diodes. Try different directions for different time and different DMMs, and the readings can be anything.

Therefore, don't trust any in-circuit measurement of components without disconnecting at least one end.